# Conditional expectation of harmonic function of Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, harmonic-functions, stochastic-analysis

I'm studying proof that if $W_t = (W_t^{(1)}, W_t^{(2)},..., W_t^{(d)})$ a $d$-dimensional Wiener process, $\mathcal{F}^W_t=\sigma(W_s: s\leq t)$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a harmonic function such that $\mathbb{E}|f(W_t)| < \infty,$ then $(f(W_t), \mathcal{F}^W_t)$ is a martingale.

The proof proceeds with following equations which I have trouble to see why work - for $t>s:$
$$\mathbb{E}(f(W_t)|\mathcal{F}^W_s)=\mathbb{E}(f(W_s + (W_t - W_s))|\mathcal{F}^W_s)=
(2\pi(t-s))^{-\frac{d}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(W_s + x)e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2(t-s)}}dx$$

I don't see how do we get $W_s$ under the integral.

Comment: I made some minor corrections - you should be conditioning on $\mathcal F^W_s$, and you should have $W_t=W_s+(W_t-W_s)$, not $W_s-(W_t-W_s)$.

Comment: That's typo obviously - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Markov property, one has $\mathbb E[f(W_t)|\mathcal F_s^W]=\mathbb E[f(W_t)|W_s]$. One proceeds as in the question, using the fact that $W_t-W_s$ is independent of $W_s$. In general, if $X$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal G$ and $Y$ has distribution $\mu$, we have
$$\mathbb E[f(X+Y)|X]=\int f(X+y)\mu(dy).$$

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the last general fact ?

Comment: It can be proved very easily. By the tower property you may assume $\mathcal G=\sigma(X)$. Let $\nu$ be the distribution of $X$. If $A$ is a Borel set, then $\mathbb E[f(X+Y);X\in A] = \int_A\int f(x+y)\mu(dy)\nu(dx) = \mathbb E[\int f(X+y)\mu(dy);X\in A]$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Since every element of $\mathcal G$ is of the form $\{X\in A\}$, we are done.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't get how you can assume $\mathcal G = \sigma(X)$. Here, $\sigma(X)$ is the smaller $\sigma$-algebra, so $\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb E[f(X+Y)|\mathcal G]\Big| \sigma(X)\Big] = \mathbb E\Big[ \mathbb E[f(X+Y)|\sigma(X)] \Big|\mathcal G\Big] = \mathbb E[f(X+Y)|\sigma(X)]$. How do you retrieve $\mathbb E[f(X+Y)|\mathcal G]$ ?

Comment: Ah, you're right - we are also using the Markov property here. Let me edit my answer.